# Restrict image access to each author even if they have the image url

Tags: php, wordpress

I have specific pages for each user with no posts inside. I've added a form for them to upload an image to the uploads folder which will be saved with a unique name for that user. This is working fine.

Now I need to restrict access to other users trying to find other submitted images by fiddling with the url. How can I secure this?

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
    if (!function_exists('wp_generate_attachment_metadata')){
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
    }
    if($_FILES)         
    {
        foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array)
        {       
            if($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK){return "upload error : " . $_FILES[$file]['error'];}

            $filename=$_FILES[$file]["name"];
            $extension=end(explode(".", $filename));
            $newfilename=$prod ."something.".$extension;                        
            $_FILES[$file]["name"] = $username . '-' . $newfilename;

            $attach_id = media_handle_upload($file,$new_post);
            echo wp_get_attachment_url($attach_id);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the name of the images using a MD5 hash

```
$newfilename=MD5($prod ."something").".".$extension;
```

Comment: It does add some security but I wonder if there's a chance of showing images only uploaded by the author instead of security only at filename. I'll use your idea in the meanwhile, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You will need to store the image as a blob in a database along with the username and image name  (as varchars). Then write a php wrapper file that mimics an image file and pass the users credentials for verification via the image url querystring. The HTML code that accesses the image would look something like this:

```
<img src="image.php?imageName=YourImageName&user=JoeBlogg">
```